# SQL - Select Rows With Values That Make Up x Percent of the Group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have searched for a while for the answer to this and it still eludes me. I have a post at SQLServerCentral ([SQLServerCentral Post](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1553523-3077-1.aspx)) for this but thought I might get more responses posting it here.

Table1:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╗
║ DealerID ║ RepairID ║
╠══════════╬══════════╣
║        1 ║        1 ║
║        1 ║        2 ║
║        1 ║        3 ║
║        1 ║        4 ║
║        1 ║        5 ║
║        1 ║        6 ║
║        1 ║        7 ║
║        1 ║        8 ║
║        1 ║        9 ║
║        1 ║       10 ║
║        2 ║       11 ║
║        2 ║       12 ║
║        2 ║       13 ║
╚══════════╩══════════╝
```

Table2:

```
╔══════════╦════════════════╗
║ RepairID ║      Tire      ║
╠══════════╬════════════════╣
║        1 ║ 225/65R17 102T ║
║        2 ║ 225/65R17 102T ║
║        3 ║ 225/65R17 102T ║
║        4 ║ 235/60R18 102V ║
║        5 ║ 235/60R18 102V ║
║        6 ║ 235/60R18 102V ║
║        7 ║ 235/60R18 102V ║
║        8 ║ 205/55R16 89H  ║
║        9 ║ 205/70R15 89H  ║
║       13 ║ 225/65R17 102T ║
╚══════════╩════════════════╝
```

Desired Output:

```
╔══════════╦════════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ DealerID ║      Tire      ║ RepairsOfThisTire ║ RepairCount ║ PercentOfTotalRepairOrders ║
╠══════════╬════════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║        1 ║ 235/60R18 102V ║                 4 ║          10 ║                         40 ║
║        1 ║ 225/65R17 102T ║                 3 ║          10 ║                         30 ║
║        1 ║ 205/55R16 89H  ║                 1 ║          10 ║                         10 ║
║        2 ║ 225/65R17 102T ║                 1 ║           3 ║                         33 ║
╚══════════╩════════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

What I need to do is calculate the percent of the like tires in table 2 using the total number of orders from table 1. I then only want the top 80% of the like tires. Using my example Dealer 1 has 10 orders total (Table1). That dealer has 9 records of tires, 4 of them are 235/60R18 102V. So the percent would be 4 / 10. This continues until I have have the top 80% as shown in the desired output table.

What I have so far (with the help of a poster at SQLServerCentral) is below. The query below is returning the correct results for DealerID 1 but it is not returning anything for DealerID 2. What am I missing and is there a more elegant way of accomplishing this?

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 (DealerID INT, RepairID INT)
INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES 
    (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),
    (1,8),(1,9),(1,10),(2,11),(2,12),(2,13)


CREATE TABLE #Table2 (RepairID INT, Tire VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES (1,'225/65R17 102T'),
    (2,'225/65R17 102T'),(3,'225/65R17 102T'),(4,'235/60R18 102V'),
    (5,'235/60R18 102V'),(6,'235/60R18 102V'),(7,'235/60R18 102V'),
    (8,'205/55R16 89H'),(9,'205/70R15 89H'),(13,'225/65R17 102T')

SELECT
    DealerId,
    COUNT(RepairID) AS 'RepairsForThisDealer'
INTO
    #temp
FROM
    #Table1
GROUP BY
    DealerId

;WITH 
Preagg AS (
    SELECT
    d.DealerID,
    Tire,
    COUNT(r.RepairID) AS RepairsOfThisTyre, 
    RepairsForThisDealer
FROM 
    #Table1 d
        INNER JOIN #Table2 r ON r.RepairID = d.RepairID INNER JOIN 
        #temp t ON t.DealerId = d.DealerId
GROUP BY d.DealerID, Tire, RepairsForThisDealer
), 
FinalAgg AS (
    SELECT DealerID, Tire, RepairsOfThisTyre, RepairsForThisDealer,
        x.PCT,
        q = SUM(x.PCT) OVER(PARTITION BY DealerID ORDER BY x.PCT DESC, Tire),
        rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DealerID ORDER BY RepairsOfThisTyre DESC)
    FROM Preagg
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT PCT = (RepairsOfThisTyre*100.00)/RepairsForThisDealer) x
)
SELECT f.* 
FROM FinalAgg f
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM FinalAgg fi
    WHERE fi.DealerID = f.DealerID
        AND q >= 80
    ORDER BY rn
) x
WHERE f.rn <= x.rn
ORDER BY f.DealerID, f.RepairsOfThisTyre DESC

DROP TABLE #Table1
DROP TABLE #Table2
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: +1 for providing test data along with your attempt and a very well presented question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rules are a little more complicated than you explain.  In particular, what happens when there is no matching repair?

Based on the output data, I surmise:

1. You only want to include matching repairs that have tires in the final output (so tire cannot be `NULL`)
2. You want to count *all* repairs, even if they are not matching

The following query accomplishes this:

```
select DealerId, Tire, count(*) as RepairsOfThisTire,
       max(cnt) as TotalRepairs,
       count(*) * 1.0 / max(cnt) as PercentOfTotal
from (select t1.*, t2.Tire,
             row_number() over (partition by t1.DealerId
                                order by (case when t2.tire is null then 1 else 0 end),
                                         t1.RepairId
                               ) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by t1.DealerId) as cnt
      from table1 t1 left join
           table2 t2
           on t1.RepairId = t2.RepairId
     ) t
where seqnum <= 0.8*cnt and tire is not null
group by DealerId, Tire
order by 1, 2;
```

The SQL Fiddle is [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e86c1/9).

I want to add:  the query that you have in the OP is unnecessarily complex.  You only need to enumerate the rows for each dealer, get the total, and apply the 80% threshold.  Using CTEs, temporary tables, and `cross apply` seems way to complicated.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be what I need. I will test it and report back. Yes I agree the OP was way too complex. Sorry I was not clear on the rules. Yes you are correct in your assumptions based on my output data.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....

The results differ here a little bit I think you have given slightly different data in your test data as compare to shown in your example.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26d30/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (DealerID INT, RepairID INT)
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES 
    (1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(1,7),
    (1,8),(1,9),(1,10),(2,11),(2,12),(2,13)


CREATE TABLE Table2 (RepairID INT, Tire VARCHAR(15))
INSERT INTO Table2 VALUES (1,'225/65R17 102T'),
    (2,'225/65R17 102T'),(3,'225/65R17 102T'),(4,'235/60R18 102V'),
    (5,'235/60R18 102V'),(6,'235/60R18 102V'),(7,'235/60R18 102V'),
    (8,'205/55R16 89H'),(9,'205/70R15 89H'),(13,'225/65R17 102T')
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT A.DealerID
      ,A.Tire
      ,A.RepairsOfThisTire
      ,B.RepairCount
      ,CAST((CAST(A.RepairsOfThisTire AS NUMERIC(10,2))
        / CAST(B.RepairCount AS NUMERIC(10,2)) )* 100.00 AS INT) AS PercentOfTotalRepairOrders
FROM
(SELECT T1.DealerID
       ,T2.Tire
       , COUNT(*) RepairsOfThisTire
FROM Table2 T2 INNER JOIN Table1 T1
ON T1.RepairID = T2.RepairID 
GROUP BY T1.DealerID
       ,T2.Tire) A
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT DealerID, COUNT(*) RepairCount 
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY DealerID) B
ON A.DealerID = B.DealerID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/26d30/1/0)**:

```
| DEALERID |           TIRE | REPAIRSOFTHISTIRE | REPAIRCOUNT | PERCENTOFTOTALREPAIRORDERS |
|----------|----------------|-------------------|-------------|----------------------------|
|        1 |  205/55R16 89H |                 1 |          10 |                         10 |
|        1 |  205/70R15 89H |                 1 |          10 |                         10 |
|        1 | 225/65R17 102T |                 3 |          10 |                         30 |
|        2 | 225/65R17 102T |                 1 |           3 |                         33 |
|        1 | 235/60R18 102V |                 4 |          10 |                         40 |
```

Comment: That is much simpler than the partition by, but the results are not what I need to produce. Dealer 1 for example should only have 3 records returned not all 4. Out of the results you display I then need to select the rows that make up 80% of the total for each dealer.